# Having issues redirecting in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

With .htaccess how can i redirect:

```
http://localhost/mvc_md/index.php/welcome/destroy 
to 
http://localhost/mvc_md/welcome/destroy
```

I'm currently using this and it isnt working:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost/mvc_md/$
RewriteRule ^(.*) localhost/$1  [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Comment: This took a while figuring out but here it is:

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/?([a-zA-Z]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?$ index.php/$1/$2/$3 [NC,L]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/?([a-zA-Z]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?$ index.php/$1/$2/$3 [NC,L]
```